# Assigning a dimension-like function to non-free semimodules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a semimodule over a commutative semiring $S$ (i.e. like a module over a ring except no additive inverses). Let $V$ be a finite subset of $M$. Call $V$ *weakly affinely independent* (w.a.i.) if it is empty or there is $v \in V$ such that

$$ v \notin \langle V \setminus \lbrace v \rbrace \rangle$$
and $V \setminus \lbrace v \rbrace$ is w.a.i.

Now, let $M$ be a semimodule that satisfies

$$ \sup \lbrace |V | : V \subseteq M \text{ is w.a.i.}\rbrace < \infty. \tag{$*$}$$
Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the set of all subsemimodules of $M$ and consider the mapping $\delta : \mathfrak{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ given by
$$ H \mapsto \lbrace |V | : V \subseteq H \text{ is w.a.i.}\rbrace.$$

It is easy to show that $\delta$ satisfies

1. $\delta H \leq \delta K$ for $H \leq K$,
2. $\delta H = \delta K$ and $H \leq K$ implies $H = K$,
3. Any maximal w.a.i. set $V$ generates $M$,
4. If we define $\delta$ similarly for another semimodule $N$ that satisfies $(*)$ and $\varphi : M \rightarrow N$ is linear, then $\delta (\varphi(M)) \leq \delta M$,
5. Any chain of subsemimodules with longer than $\delta M + 1$ has at least one improper inclusion.

In particular, for $M$ a vector space, $\delta$ coincides with the dimension of a subspace. For the work I am trying to do, I need one more property:

6. If $\delta \varphi(M) = \delta M$, then $\varphi$ is injective.

It is clear that this is the case when $M$ is a vector space or $M$ is finite. The converse is also easy to show. But is this true in general? I cannot seem to find a proof, even for case $\delta M = 1$. If $\varphi$ is an endomorphism and $\delta M = 1$ however, this is indeed true.

I would be interested in any sort of pointers on this, ideas in which direction to work in, or even different definitions of w.a.i. that would make 6. true.

**Edit**: I think it's easy enough to show tha there is a maximal w.a.i. set $V$ in $M$ with $\varphi(M)$ maximal w.a.i., but so it seems like it would be possible to construct a (linear) left inverse to $\varphi$ from this. However, since
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i \varphi(v_i) =  \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu_i \varphi(v_i) $$
does not seem to guarantee
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i v_i =  \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu_i v_i $$
in general, I'm not sure that this would be well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $\delta\varphi(M) = \delta(M)$ does not imply that $\varphi$ is injective.

Take $S = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and let $M = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ viewed as a semimodule over itself.  Then $\delta(M) = 1$, and the maximal w.a.i. subsets are the $\{\lambda\}$ with $\lambda>0$.

Take now $N = \{0\} \cup \{\infty\}$ with the obvious action of $S$ on it.  Then $\delta(N) = 1$, and its only w.a.i. subset is $\{\infty\}$.

Finally, let $\varphi:M\to N$ be defined by
$$
 \varphi(m) = \begin{cases} \infty & \textrm{if $m\neq 0$} \\
                            0 & \textrm{if $m=0$.} \end{cases}
$$
Then $\varphi$ is a surjective and non-injective morphism of semimodules, and $\delta(M) = 1 = \delta(N) = \delta\varphi(M)$.  We thus have a counterexample to property 6.

Comment: Thank you, nice. What about the case when $\varphi$ is an endomorphism though? Your example doesn't seem to extend in an obvious way to this case.

Comment: To be more general, it seems to be that at least in the case $\delta M = 1$, if $\varphi(v) = \varphi(u)$, then $v = \tau u$ for some $\tau \in S$ that acts trivially on $N$. Can this be extended to larger $\delta M$?

Comment: @tolUene I don't have an immediate example when $\varphi$ is an endomorphism.  I won't have much time to think about it this week, but I'll try to come back to it later on.